# convert unicode to string php

Tags: php, json, utf-8, utf8-decode

My actual string is

**Mom  said, "I  love  this  one."
Jake  said, "I  don’t  get   it."**

But instead it

In my database in one column the value is saving like that i cant change

**Mom  said, â€œI  love  this  one.â€
Jake  said, â€œI  donâ€™t  get   it.â€**

I am fetching that from query and do json_encode then it display the output like this in json string

**Mom said, \u00e2\u20ac\u0153I love this one.\u00e2\u20ac\u009d\n\nJake said, \u00e2\u20ac\u0153I don\u00e2\u20ac\u2122t get it.\u00e2\u20ac\u009d\n**

So please tell me how to decode this unicode into double quotes.

thanks in advance

Comment: check your table collation in db..change to UTF8

Comment: @swapnesh just "UTF" is a broad statement.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst yeah my bad ..missed 8 lol..edit committed :)

Comment: Are you using `utf8_encode` in your code?

Comment: yes i have tried with that

Answer (score 3):

The data that you already have probably needs to be passed through `utf8_decode()` (not `utf8_encode()`).

To ensure smooth sailing in the future, you should make sure your whole pipe is UTF-8. This is non-trivial, sadly. Off the top of my head, places that need to be checked:

- HTTP daemon's default encoding

  - For Apache, add to .htaccess or httpd.conf: `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`
- PHP's default_encoding

  - Add in .htaccess or server config: `php_value default_charset "UTF-8"`
- HTTP's header content-type charset

  - `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`
- HTML's meta content-type charset

  - `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`
- PHP's MySQL connection charset

  - `mysql_set_charset('utf8');`
- MySQL's database default charset and collation

  - Use charset `utf8` and collation `utf8_general_ci`
- MySQL's table and column charset

  - Use charset `utf8` and collation `utf8_general_ci`

And if you need to output values that may contain unwanted HTML or XML, use `htmlentities($var, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');` instead of simply `htmlentities($var);`

Also, use the `mb_*` functions where possible, such as `mb_strlen()` and `mb_substr()`.

Answer (score -1):

Change your table collation to `latin1_swedish_ci`

With special char you can also do something like this

for displaying the data from mysql

```
$str=html_entity_decode(stripslashes($rows[4]));
```

for inserting the data with special characters into mysql

```
$var_name=htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($detail));
```

Comment: `html_entity_decode()`, `stripslashes()`, and `htmlentities()` have no place in the communication with MySQL, as MySQL does not care about HTML and values returned from MySQL are not escaped with slashes.